# Apache crashes with munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer after update to php7 on Jessie

Tags: apache, memory, debian, php-7

I recently updated to php 7.0.4 on my server running a Debian 8.

here is what `dpkg -l | grep php` gives me:

```
ii  libapache2-mod-php7.0          7.0.4-1~dotdeb+8.1           amd64        server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (Apache 2 module)
ii  php-common                     21-1~dotdeb+8.1              all          Common files for PHP packages
ii  php-readline                   21-1~dotdeb+8.1              all          readline module for PHP [default]
ii  php7.0                         7.0.4-1~dotdeb+8.1           all          server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (metapackage)
ii  php7.0-cli                     7.0.4-1~dotdeb+8.1           amd64        command-line interpreter for the PHP scripting language
ii  php7.0-common                  7.0.4-1~dotdeb+8.1           all          Common files for packages built from the PHP source
ii  php7.0-curl                    7.0.4-1~dotdeb+8.1           amd64        CURL module for PHP
ii  php7.0-gd                      7.0.4-1~dotdeb+8.1           amd64        GD module for PHP
ii  php7.0-imap                    7.0.4-1~dotdeb+8.1           amd64        IMAP module for PHP
ii  php7.0-intl                    7.0.4-1~dotdeb+8.1           amd64        Internationalisation module for PHP
ii  php7.0-json                    7.0.4-1~dotdeb+8.1           amd64        JSON module for PHP
ii  php7.0-mcrypt                  7.0.4-1~dotdeb+8.1           amd64        libmcrypt module for PHP
ii  php7.0-mysql                   7.0.4-1~dotdeb+8.1           amd64        MySQL module for PHP
ii  php7.0-opcache                 7.0.4-1~dotdeb+8.1           amd64        Zend OpCache module for PHP
ii  php7.0-readline                7.0.4-1~dotdeb+8.1           amd64        readline module for PHP
```

My php applications run fine most of the time.But on some requests I just get a Page being generated for no foreseeable reason.

The `/var/log/apache2/error.log` states in such a case:

```
*** Error in `/usr/sbin/apache2': munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x00007efc6ddb4a50 ***
*** Error in `/usr/sbin/apache2': munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x00007efc6dd5cad0 ***
[Wed Mar 09 11:26:44.940931 2016] [core:notice] [pid 28486] AH00052: child pid 29338 exit signal Aborted (6)
[Wed Mar 09 11:26:44.941017 2016] [core:notice] [pid 28486] AH00052: child pid 29344 exit signal Aborted (6)
*** Error in `/usr/sbin/apache2': munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x00007efc6dd5cad0 ***
[Wed Mar 09 11:26:46.942581 2016] [core:notice] [pid 28486] AH00052: child pid 29347 exit signal Aborted (6)
```

I'll give some more information:

Syntax:

```
$ apachectl configtest
Syntax OK
```

Version:

```
apachectl -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)
Server built:   Nov 28 2015 14:05:48
```

Before the php update I did not see those errors. What is wrong here? Or how can I better find the source? I am lost here because this error occures kind of random. Sometimes the same request succeeds that faild with this error a minute ago. I would apprechiate your help.

Comment: I have the same issue. Apache2 version same as your, php 7.0.8.1.Do you find any solutions for this?

Comment: I downgraded back to php 5.6 on that server. And thus I cannot test the suggested solutions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's now the second time we have been hit hard by the very same issue.

It happens when running PHP 7.0 on a up to date debian.
This will break any type of website system which heavily uses regular expression.
We have seen it iwth Neos (neos.io) or Typo3 (starting with 6.2).

In case it's not possible to use the testing version of the libpcre3.
Someone can disable the just in time compiling within the php.ini

1. Edit your php.ini add `pcre.jit=0` anywhere you like
2. Restart your apache
3. Be happy

Comment: Disabling jit worked in my case. I noticed this problem only seems to exist in PHP >7.1.3. I wonder if it will be fixed upstream?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same version and solved by upgrading `libpcre3` like @Kevin Fischer write.

I was upgrade `libpcre3` package form *2:8.35-3.3+deb8u4* (stable) to *2:8.38-3.1* (testing) version.

Step by step:

1. Add line `deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian testing main contrib non-free` to /etc/apt/sources.list
2. Create file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99default-release` with content: `APT::Default-Release "stable";`
3. Run command `apt-get update` from root
4. Run command `apt-get -t testing install libpcre3` to install testing version of `libpcre3` package
5. Restart your server and check logs, error should be disappears.

For more info to install testing package see [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/22414/how-can-i-run-debian-stable-but-install-some-packages-from-testing?newreg=e614376e99304997b98124b97ed0071e).

**Warning!** Testing packages can works incorrectly! Update in your own risk or wait new release.

Answer (score 1):

We've just had a similiar situation, where one of our framework's components would fail us with:

`` *** Error in `php': munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x00007fdce5550060 *** ``

I can't tell you anything about the bug itself, but the cause of it was a broken `libpcre3` version, namely `8.35-3.3+deb8u4`. We we're running a custom build, because PHP7 requires JIT support from libpcre3, which isn't included in the default one our Ubuntu version comes with (`Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, 8.31-2ubuntu2.3`). Upgrading the `libpcre3` version solved the problem for us.

Answer (score 0):

I also kept getting those nasty apache crashes, but none of the solutions above and on other websites were working for me.
After a lot of trial and error, I found out the root cause on my system.
I manually edited the PHP configuration and added two extensions. Both for Microsoft's SQL Server.
I added the following lines to the php.ini

```
extension=sqlsrv.so
extension=pdo_sqlsrv
```

I did not notice that I fogot the ".so" at the pdo driver.
After changing the lines as shown below, the Apache service is running fine again.

```
extension=sqlsrv.so
extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so
```